# Show parameter spfile showing no value

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c

My database was showing spfile earlier  but then I had to increase sga size and hence restarted database. After restart when I type command 'show parameter spfile', it shows no value. also the sga size was still the same.

Comment: If you have a SPFILE backup, try to restore it and restart the database instance.

Comment: What was the solution? Can you share what did help in your case with future generations?

Comment: Actually the issue was that I had started the db using pfile hence the parameter spfile was not coming after that.

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle instance can be started using two types of settings files ( SPFILE or PFILE ). If your instance show SPFILE empty, that means that your instance has started using a PFILE. The default location of PFILE and SPFILE files is $ORACLE_HOME/dbs:

- spfile --> spfile<<instance_name>>.ora
- pfile  --> init<<instance_name>>.ora

If you don't have the pfile with that name, your instance is starting using init.ora. Remember that the spfile is a binary file.

```
$ file spfileodcgrc1r.ora
spfilemydatabase.ora: data
$ file initodcgrc1r.ora
initmydatabase.ora: ASCII text
```

Try this:

```
SQL> CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE;

SQL> SHOW SGA 

-- that will show the parameters of your SGA 

SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE 
SQL> STARTUP 

-- we here started using spfile

SQL> show parameter spfile

-- it must show you the spfile and its default location

-- change your sga parameter with option scope=spfile 

-- example

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_MAX_SIZE = XXG SCOPE=SPFILE; 

-- change whatever you need to change regarding your SGA setup

SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
SQL> STARTUP
```